# WIFI no longer working for no apparent reason.....on 12.04

Tags: wireless

Since today, my wifi LED is off, I cannot enable it and it seems that the OS cannot detect the Wifi card at all. It's like it has disappeared! 
I tried BIOS default reset- didn't work
I didn't update anything....
Do you have any idea to help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start by typing `lspci` in a terminal to see if it is there. If it is try `rfkill unblock all`.